# Is this the correct way to use html role?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, html

As I have seen that the `role` attribute is fully supported in HTML5 semantics doctype. I have used it in `JQuery` selectors such as:

```
<div role="inputForm">
  <div role="field">
    Name : <input type="text" role="name" />
  </div>
  <div role="field">
    Address : <textarea type="text" role="address"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div role="field">
    Country : <select role="country"></select>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var inputForm = $("div[role='inputForm']");
var fields = $(inputForm.find("div[role='field']"));
var nameField = $(inputForm.find("input[role='name']"));
</script>
```

As I have known, the same attribute is being used in `JqGrid`, grid plugin for `JQuery`.

I think that this selector is more efficient and modular than class / id based selector. However, is this the correct use of role attribute in HTML5? Or is there any risk of doing this design?

If this kind of design does not supported / recommended as HTML best practice, is there any way to achieve the same?

I cannot find any articles or supported documents for this kind of usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. HTML5 [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#wai-aria):

> Authors may use the ARIA `role` and `aria-*` attributes on HTML elements, in accordance with the requirements described in the ARIA specifications, except where these conflict with the strong native semantics described below.

Your values `inputForm` and `field` are [not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#role_definitions).

*If* you use the `role` attribute correctly, you can of course use it as a hook in CSS and JS, too.

---

> I think that this selector is more efficient and modular than class / id based selector.

Your actual intention seems to be to find an identifier that can be used on several (third party) sites, without the risk of [name collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_collision).

You could use the `class`, the `id`, or the [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes). To make collisions unlikely, you could use a "rare" prefix, for example your domain name (`example.com`):

```
<div class="com-example-foo"></div> 
<div id="com-example-foo"></div> 
<div data-com-example="foo"></div> <!-- preferred, because the prefix is not part of the value -->
```

Another possibility would be to use a custom vocabulary with [Microdata or RDFa](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633). As you can use your own URIs as value, it’s very unlikely that anyone else would use these (unless you publish your vocabulary and it’s useful for others ;-)).

Comment: Right on the spot. That is exactly what I aim for. Looks like the `data-*` attributes is the better one. Now I need to search for any source supporting the use of `data-*` attribute for jquery selector.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you should be using id instead of role (though not for your `role="field"` attributes... those should be classes).

It short, your role attribute values are not being used as intended per the WAI-ARIA specification.

The role attribute should be used to assign semantic meaning to document elements, and there are a limited set of valid and appropriate values defined by the Accessible Rich Internet Applications Suite (ARIA), to make Web content and Web applications more accessible.

An extensive list of the valid role attribute values can be found at the W3C spec documentation for The Roles Model: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#abstract_roles

Comment: Looks like my worriness has a reason after all. Say that if I want to remove the use of role attributes in this case, is there any way to achieve the same? (I'll update my question)

Comment: Id is recommended to be unique for each element. If there are two or more element with same purpose here (such as `name input` in different form) I need to use `[form_name]_name` as id instead. Id selector also makes it hard to make the javascript library reuseable (e.g the element must has same id as defined in library). Using class is good enough, however the class name must be unique for not collide with custom css class name (such as `.address` usually has css class defined).

Comment: That's interesting... well, ids MUST be unique... and the purpose of using class is that those can be shared. Again, if you're insisting that your class names must be unique, then you should be using id. You shouldn't have two or more instances of an id, as you propose... but if the shared id is in another form, and they're not both loaded into the same document, then it wouldn't matter insofar as your JS is concerned. You could just give your forms a unique class name and then set that as the parent reference in your jQuery selector.

Comment: I may be unclear with the unique class name. What I mean unique is that the class name must not has common name, which usually be used in css class, such as `.address` or `.email`. It is good if the class name is `.js_address` instead since the name is rather unique, and not usually used in css class. As for the `Id` selector it is not flexible, especially when rendering items such as questions in or comments SO.

Comment: @Fendy that's easy to get aroung, create a prefix naming convention that identifies class is there for manipulation purposes not style. Or use `data-` attributes which can be arbitrarily named